# iOS10 UNNotificationServiceExtension not called

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios10, ios-app-extension, unnotificationserviceextension

Im implementing new iOS10 extension to use rich notifications. Im trying to test it on push notifications but is not working, I just receive a simple notification and is not going through the extension.

I did all that it's specified in the official sites and some other places:

- I have my app up and running with push notifications and the right provisioning profile
- I added a new target to my app, a Notification Service Extension
- Implemented my own code (it doesn't matter really because is not even entering to the new class)
- Also I had to set a provisioning profile for this extension, I just use one with a wildcard, I don't see any documentation specifying if the extension target has to enable push notifications capability, in that case I would need a specific provisioning for this one, at the moment I just use a wildcard prov, anyway it matches (it must match) the profile I use in the app target, and push notifications capability is enabled for the app target only.
- I added UNNotificationExtensionCategory and NSExtensionPointIdentifier. Also Im sending the category as part of the push payload from the server.

As I said, I get the notification but never goes through the extension. I see how the OS tries to load the extension but then throws an error with no relevant description to identify the problem:

```
Dec 31 21:00:00 iPhone SpringBoard(libextension.dylib)[51] <Notice>: calling plugIn beginUsing:   
Dec 31 21:00:57 iPhone pkd[86] <Notice>: assigning plug-in com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension(1.0) to plugin sandbox   
Dec 31 21:03:57 iPhone pkd[86] <Notice>: enabling pid=51 for plug-in com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension(1.0) 38BB5FF1-2597-42E0-B950-169DBFA80573 /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8C47706-C0EC-4FB1-ABA7-0118372F6900/testapp.app/PlugIns/NotificationWithAttachmentExtension.appex   
Dec 31 21:00:53 iPhone SpringBoard(PlugInKit)[51] <Notice>: plugin com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension interrupted   
Dec 31 21:03:56 iPhone SpringBoard(PlugInKit)[51] <Notice>: Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension}   
Jun 29 13:33:36 iPhone SpringBoard(libextension.dylib)[51] <Notice>: PlugInKit error in beginUsing:   
Jun 17 23:33:04 iPhone SpringBoard(libextension.dylib)[51] <Notice>: killing invalid plugIn   
Dec 31 21:00:00 iPhone SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[51] <Error>: Extension error whilst trying to modify push notification F502-9B36: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension}   
Dec 31 21:00:00 iPhone SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[51] <Notice>: [com.test.app] Saving notification F502-9B36   
Dec 31 21:00:00 iPhone SpringBoard(libextension.dylib)[51] <Notice>: completed calling plugIn beginUsing: for pid: 0
```

**Relevant extension .plist:**

```
  <dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
      <key>UNNotificationExtensionCategory</key>
      <string>attachmentCategory</string>
      <key>UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio</key>
      <real>1</real>
    </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.usernotifications.service</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).NotificationService</string>
  </dict>
```

What's wrong or missing?

Comment: Try adding this: <key>UNNotificationExtensionDefaultContentHidden</key>
   <true/> to `NSExtensionAttributes`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? If so could you please describe it or share a link as we are running into a similar issue...

Comment: @BenMarten, finally I have this working correctly, and this is what I remember from this issue:

Comment: comment is below as an answer, it was too long to put it as a comment...

Comment: A bit offtopic, but how do you get the springboard log? Dec 31 21:00:00 iPhone SpringBoard

Comment: @JuanPedroLozano It's from the Device's logs - You can find it at Window -> Devices -> Select current device.

Comment: Apparently the extension runs as a separate app (Which is why breakpoints aren't hit). But I did learn that sending a category with your notification makes it so the app doesn't display action buttons or images.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally I have this working correctly, and this is what I remember from this issue.

1) Do not use devices with iOS10 beta version, because one of the problems I had was because I was using a beta version.

2) only the app requres APNS entitlements, this is not required for the privisoning used for the extension.

3) I was using a provisioning profile matching the id of the extension (not wildcard), anyway I cannot confirm if it works fine or not with wildcard.

4) **NSExtensionAttributes are not required**, just use NSExtensionPointIdentifier and NSExtensionPrincipalClass for the extension .plist. Unless you are using your own layout

5) This is working even using iOS 9 token registration methods.

6) don't forget mutable-content value in the payload coming in the push notification, this is the only mandatory value you need from the server to go through the extension.

I think this covers all the problems I had

Comment: we need to create separate bundle id and provisioning profile in member center for UNNotificationServiceExtension ?

Comment: APNs is required for app extension, or else it will NOT compile.

Comment: same not working please can someone share the code of app delegate what he did????????

Comment: set everything correctly. But still its not working :(

Answer (score 76):

What also might do the trick is check your deployment target for the extension. Mine was set at `10.2` while the device I was testing on was (still) using 10.1

After altering the deployment target to `10.0` the `UNNotificationServiceExtension` instance was called perfectly

Comment: Great. I did a same mistake. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Oh my God! This is really nice and simple solution. I didn't even think to check this.

Comment: Thank you! THANK YOU SO MUCH @basvk 
I integrated a push library for one of the targets and then had to reintegrate for the second target during the same week. BOTH TIMES I wasted so much time with not checking the target and ended up on your answer

Comment: Thank you so much it helped me a lot. I was using 10.1 device when extension deployment target was 10.3

Comment: Face palm. I'm in this issue the 3rd time. This answer helped me the 2nd time. Next time I promise to send cake. 

Comment: After wasting a couple of days, this finally fixed it. Thanks you @basvk

Comment: I think this happens, because Xcode is setting it to the latest SDK when you create the extension. Therefore i ran into the same issue on one of my testing devices ...

Comment: you good but if you attach the screen shot its will aslo very helpfull

Comment: Thank you, I'm working in the tutorial I follow the exact the same but not working. You same my days. @basvk

Comment: @basvk Thank you that worked in still 2022 

Answer (score 28):

And if you've done everything correctly, don't forget to attach it to the process.

After running the app that contains the extension:

1. Set your breakpoint in the extension
2. Select Debug / Attach to Process by PID or name
3. Enter the name of the extension target
4. Trigger the push notification

Comment: +1 This answer was super helpful as I forgot that this is a separate process and was expecting breakpoints to work if I was just running the app process.

Comment: NotificationService class is not appearing there!!

Comment: try adding it manually, when you start typing the name it should appear @Basir Alam

Comment: @BasirAlam from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48507016/how-to-debug-an-ios-app-extension/62200031#62200031) _If you're trying to debug an extension that is trigged by the OS then you need to do something so that the OS triggers it. Only then you can attach it to the debugger._

Comment: was not aware that you could do this, thanks buddy!

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Firebase, then try changing the payload as:

```
{
   “aps” : {
      “category” : “SECRET”,
      “mutable_content” : true,
      “alert” : {
         “title” : “Secret Message!”,
         “body”  : “(Encrypted)”
     },
   },
   “ENCRYPTED_DATA” : “Salted__·öîQÊ$UDì_¶Ù∞è   Ω^¬%gq∞NÿÒQùw”
}
```

The mutable_content field maps to the mutable-content field on APNs.
For more details, go through this [link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/70#issuecomment-280182095).

Comment: Using the regular non-firebase API, the field is named "mutable-content" and must be adjacent to the "alert" attribute

Comment: @CalS right! Apparently, if the value of  "mutable-content" is anything different from "false" or 0, the notification is considered to have a mutable content.

Answer (score 10):

Swift 5 Easy way

```
 this is very easy way just do it like this
 Firebase Side should be like:
 
 {
 “aps” : {
    “category” : “SECRET”,
    “mutable_content” : true, //this is the important line for ios
    “alert” : {
       “title” : “Secret Message!”,
       “body”  : “(Encrypted)”
     },
   },
  “ENCRYPTED_DATA” : “Salted__·öîQÊ$UDì_¶Ù∞è   Ω^¬%gq∞NÿÒQùw”
 }
```

[image]

Comment: This work for me, make me like a fool :joy:

Answer (score 10):

You must set the deployment target to be the same on all your targets. I wonder why this is not done automatically by XCode :/ .. Apple loves to waste the developers' time smh...

Comment: saved my day. I had 14.0 on my main app and 14.1 on the service extension. Was not working. Changed service extension to 14.0 and it worked immediately. Thanks!

Comment: OMG HOW THIS IS A THING THANK YOU

Comment: THANKS! this worked! Incredible that Xcode doesn't do this automatically :(

Answer (score 9):

Came here the second time. The first time, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42004804/129202) helped me, the second time, it didn't. After a lot of (internal) swearing I found out that I had somehow accidentally removed the extension from Embedded Binaries in my main app target. When I added the extension back, my extension would be called again.

So check this:

1. Click on your app project to the left.
2. Click on your main app target.
3. Choose General.
4. Under Embedded Binaries, make sure your extension is listed, if not, add it.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like your plist is mixing 2 plists.
There are 2 extensions in play:

1. Notification Content Extension - responsible for displaying the content via a view controller
2. Notification Service Extension - responsible for fetching content in the background before notification is displayed

Here is the plist for `Notification Content Extension` target:

[image]

Here is the plist for `Notification Service Extension` target:

[image: r]

Comment: but in my case Im not using a custom UI, Im just using the extension to modify the content only (actually is not even going through my code, so let's say Im just sending the content as it is). now I see NSExtensionAttributes is requires for content extension, but looks like this is not my case. This is the first documentation I followed and when the post started, where my implementation didn't work:  https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension

Comment: link is broken. are you sending `mutable-content: 1` in the aps payload?

Comment: yes, in fact the error I see in the device log if when the OS already found my extension but didn't run the code. So mutable-content was validated already at that time (without this will not even check for notif extensions)

Comment: have you figured it out ?

Comment: Did u found any solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem, what solved it for me was removing the extension from Embedded Binaries and adding it again.

Comment: This. Unbelievable, but THIS is what solved this for me. I was banging my head against the wall for two days.

Comment: After looooong long hours this was the fix for me. I've implemented rich push a lot of times. But this time somehow it didn't work for my new project. This answer changed something now it is working. Thank you.

Comment: Unbelievable, this should be upvoted more! Saved my day after 4 hours of swearing ^_^

Comment: this is a crazy fix - give it a try, fixed the issue for me as well!

Answer (score 4):

After trying many of the possible fixes already given without success, it dawned on me that a framework had been mistakenly added to our extension target rather than the unit test target.

Removing the framework and targeting 10.2 allowed my extension to be called once again.

If you are curious as to which framework for whatever reason you can find it here: https://github.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks

Comment: Saved me from a big one, buddy. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking to just trigger a breakpoint in your app’s notification extension, the process is pretty simple in Xcode 11.3:

1. Select the scheme of the extension (not the parent app scheme).
2. Select `Edit Scheme`.
3. Select the Executable to be your parent app.
4. Uncheck `Debug executable`. By unchecking this, you are informing Xcode to debug the extension instead of the parent app. This is key to getting Xcode to stop within the extension’s breakpoints.
5. Select `Automatically` under the `Launch` option.
6. Run the scheme of the extension (not the parent app).
7. Send your device a notification. Profit.

Unless some other stuff triggers Xcode’s moodiness, the above settings should ensure that whenever you select and run the extension scheme, the breakpoints within the extension will be hit. You can go back and check `Debug executable` in step 4 if you want Xcode to stop at breakpoints within the parent app.

Pro-tip: Don’t forget to add `"mutable-content": 1` within the notification JSON payload, otherwise you will have a major sad (iOS won’t invoke the extension without that key).

---

Here’s a picture of my scheme editor dialog for the notification extension:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was what I forget to select NotificationServiceExtension in Scheme as particular app instead of "my application" where I try to use it. So I've been running "my app" and waited for breakpoints in code of another app (NotificationServiceExtension) and and that's why they never showed up. I tried every suggestions before that.

Comment: I wasted four hours of my life until I found this solution. God bless you!

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with this I finally made this work for me by just changing 2 things.

1. The bundleID of the NotificationServiceExtension target must be a different one. Preferred style com.companyname.appname.notificationservice(whatever). Setting the same bundleID of the app causes a failure in building to device.
2. The main thing is the deployment target. I was double checking this with app's target but we must also check the deployment target of the newly created NotificationServiceExtenion's target which is by default the latest version. Set that to the minimum iOS version you would like to support but greater than ios 10.

Note: Make sure you have "mutable-content" : 1 in remote payload.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

The `public func didReceiveNotificationRequest(request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)` method in `UNNotificationServiceExtension` has changed between swift versions.

Some of the online examples are not up to date.

Make sure the method you're overriding in your custom subclass of `UNNotificationServiceExtension`

I had:

`func didReceive(request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler:(UNNotificationContent) -> Void)`

which didn't work until i changed to:

`func didReceiveNotificationRequest(request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)`

Comment: thanks for the comment. I just checked but I have the right method, Im using Objective-c, and I have exactly the same method it's in the interface (UNNotificationServiceExtension)

Comment: Got it. Are you sending "category" in the push payload (server-side) ?

Comment: probably no, we had the basic functionality for our APNS server, and we added what apple suggested only (mutable-content and any extra info we want to read on the client).

Comment: I tried setting this category following apple specs (plist config and server side value too), but still not working. I see apple specs mention "NSExtensionAttribute" but lot of sample codes are using "NSExtensionAttributes" (plural), I tried both just in case, but I still have exactly the same result. it is very frustrating to have this error with no description at all of what is wrong, a simple message explaining what Apple is trying to valide would be enough to identify the issue...

Comment: It's definitely `NSExtensionAttributes` can you post you relevant plist ?

Comment: `<key>NSExtension</key>  
  <dict>  
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>  
    <dict>  
      <key>UNNotificationExtensionCategory</key>  
      <string>attachmentCategory</string>  
      <key>UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio</key>  
      <real>1</real>  
    </dict>  
  <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>  
  <string>com.apple.usernotifications.service</string>  
  <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>  
<string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).NotificationService</string>  
  </dict>`

Comment: I added more info to my post

Comment: make sure you're sending `category`: `attachmentCategory` in your `aps` payload

Comment: yes, that's done, and I see is coming correctly to the device (there's a log showing aps data)

Comment: is NSExtensionAttributes necessary? I'm able to get it to work on an development build without it.

Comment: You'll be able to build without a problem, it's just that the push will not trigger the Notification Content Extension

Answer (score 2):

My issue was two fold. The first probably was that I had set the `Info.plist` property NSExtensionPrincipalClass to `bundle.identifier.NotificationService` instead of `ProductModuleName.NotificationService`. Module name is the default, but I had erroneously changed to the identifier when debugging some other things related to different schemes and different targets.

The second issue was that I tested by running the notification service target. For me it worked much better when running the app target. I saw some other people recommending to use the notification service target to enable debugging. But that works fine when running the app target as well. You'll have to attach the debugger to your notification service manually though.

The way I discovered the above was to create a new test project with minimal code. In hindsight I definitely recommend that approach instead of trying out all the different solutions found on stackoverflow etc

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have 'None' configuration set. Look at the screenshot. With other parameters `didReceive` doesn't work.

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPrEe.png)

Answer (score 1):

Other possibility is to check category name in plist file of UNNotificationContentExtension.

String value of "UNNotificationExtensionCategory" in plist and "category/click_action" of payload should be same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on Xcode 12.3 and Swift 5.2, and when I backed off the Main Project Target and Notification Service Extension Target from **iOS 14.2** to **iOS 13.2**, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The system executes your notification content app extension only when a remote notification’s payload contains the following information:

- The payload must include the `mutable-content` key with a value of `1`.
- The payload must include an alert dictionary with *title*, *subtitle*, or
  *body* information.

> Specifying the remote notification payload:

```
{
   “aps” : {
      “category” : “SECRET”,
      “mutable-content” : 1,
      “alert” : {
         “title” : “Secret Message!”,
         “body”  : “(Encrypted)”
     },
   },
   “ENCRYPTED_DATA” : “Salted__·öîQÊ$UDì_¶Ù∞è   Ω^¬%gq∞NÿÒQùw”
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all good suggestions, which helped me fixed my mismatch with deployment target and missing mutable-content. But for me I still had issues getting the NSE to be called. I found the solution in the source code from this blog, https://medium.com/gits-apps-insight/processing-notification-data-using-notification-service-extension-6a2b5ea2da17. I was missing *Embed App Extensions* that copied the extension to my app. Why this was missing, I'm not sure, I have not seen this as a required step in the different tutorials I have read.

The *Embed App Extension* is just a "Copy File Phase" that has been renamed, as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71031519/3080858

[image]

This tutorial was also very helpful setting up the different App Ids, App Groups, Profiles etc:
https://blog.logrocket.com/implement-push-notifications-react-native-onesignal/