# How to debug an iOS app extension in Xcode 13?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-app-extension, xcode13

I know this question has been asked and answered for other Xcode versions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48507016/16602527) and other places, but I would like to know if the solution remains the same for Xcode 13.

Basically, I am trying to debug an app extension by printing with `NSLog`, following these steps (from the above linked post):

> Go to Xcode >> Debug >> Attach to process >> Then just select your
> appExtension target

However, I don't see where it is being printed? I have confirmed that the code is getting run because after performing the above steps, I have a break point just after my NSLog which is being triggered; but I don't see my log in the Xcode console... Is it printing somewhere else?