# How to deal with Xcode "Embed App Extension" build phase

Tags: xcode

When creating a "Share extension" via adding new target Xcode adds build phase named "Embed App Extension" in app "Build Phases" tab of app target settings. It is possible to remove this phase, but if you try to add it by pressing "+" at the left upper corner you'll find "Embed App Extension" is not listed among available options.

Why is it so? How to embed app extension to the target app without adding new target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Embed App Extension" is just a "Copy File Phase" that has been renamed.

So just use the "+" at the left upper corner, select "New Copy Files Phase", expand it and manually set its properties.

You can also double click on the name of the phase to rename it back to "Embed App Extension".

Comment: You want to copy the appropriate .appex file to the "Plugins and Foundation Extensions" destination.